# Check that class was called in a with statement

Tags: python, contextmanager

I am building a class that people are supposed to use with a context manager:

```py
with MyClass(params) as mc:
    mc.do_things()
    ...
```

I was wondering whether it was possible to make sure that people called it this way, and that code looking like this:

```py
mc = MyClass(params)
mc.do_things()
```

would raise an exception or an error message. I suppose I could set a private variable when `mc.__enter__()` is executed, and throw an exception if that variable isn't set when `mc.do_things()` is called. Is there a better way to do this?

I'm not looking for bullet-proof security, just to mitigate the chances that users misuse the interface by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the cleanest way, but a context manager doesn't have to return its own instance from the `__enter__` method, therefore you can do this:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __enter__(self):
        return MyOtherClass()

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def foo(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    
class MyOtherClass:
    def foo(self):
        print(f"I am {type(self)}")
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This will work:
    with MyClass() as x:
        x.foo()

    # This will fail:
    y = MyClass()
    y.foo()
```

Obviously others can still instantiate `MyOtherClass` if they really want to.